# Expanded really bad

Tags: flutter

I want `TextField` to be centered with the front child

[image]

But when it's wrapped in `Expanded`, it's really bad

[image]

This is part of row

```dart
    Container(
            child: Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff666666),
                  fontSize: 15.sp,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: S
                        .of(context)
                        .phoneNumber,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFCCCCCC),
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none),
                inputFormatters: [
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF1FA2FF),
              ),
            ))
```

update: full Row code

```
             Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage("img/phone_icon.png"),
                      width: 36.w,
                      height: 19.h,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "+60",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: Color(0xff666666), fontSize: 15.sp),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.w, 0, 14.w, 0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      width: 1.w,
                      height: 12.h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffCCCCCC)),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff666666),
                          fontSize: 15.sp,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: S.of(context).phoneNumber,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFFCCCCCC),
                            ),
                            border: InputBorder.none),
                        inputFormatters: [
                          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                        ],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        cursorColor: Color(0xFF1FA2FF),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve so that I can help you?

Comment: @Uni I updated the UI in the first picture

I hope child is in the middle of row

Comment: You should receive what you want if you give your row mainaxis and crossaxis alignment center

Comment: You can try @MarcelDz's solution or try using spacer instead of the expanded widget.

Comment: @MarcelDz
I added mainaxisalignment in row: MainAxisAlignment.center ,

crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center ,

But it didn't work

Comment: please provide the full code you have with the error, so i can help you

Comment: @Uni
If you remove expanded, a catch will be generated.  need to put textfield in expanded

Comment: @MarcelDz Maybe I constrained the height of row?

If I don't limit the height, expanded will become larger

Comment: @CoderZeng What do you mean with a catch will be generated? What I meant was to use Spacer instead of Expanded. Just replace Expanded() with Spacer()

Comment: @CoderZeng I provided you an example and some hopefully helpful information to get started with flexible widgets. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I want to show you a quick example I just created showing different widgets all perfectly aligned:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(height: 300, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1, color: Colors.yellow, child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(width: 10),
      Text('First Element'),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
Text('Second Element'),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.volume_up),
          tooltip: 'Increase volume by 10',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
    ]));
  }
}
```

The error you described you are getting is caused because `Row()` is a flexible widget which needs propably a definition of height and width of some of the parents. Your row doesnt have any parents in that construction which can be used as information for the row on how to make it alignable `Expandable()` doesn't count for that, as it is also a flexible widget.

In detail you are nesting elements.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

This is a great article for better understanding of the ui elements:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

**Also nice to know:**
***Rows and Columns***
Two of the most important Widgets to master, and the bane of every Flutter developer's existence, are Rows and Columns. Whether you want to create a complex news app or a some simple buttons with an icon and text aligned to each other, you have to nest Rows and Columns… And when you nest them, all kinds of things can start getting very weird, very fast.
Rows and Columns both extend the Flex class, meaning they're Subclasses and Flex is their Superclass. The only real difference between a Row and Column is that the Row is a Flex that has it's direction property hardcoded to horizontal, and the Column's is hardcoded to vertical.
One thing that tends to confuse a lot of people new to Flutter is when your Row or Column blows up in your face, the error never says Row or Column. Newcomers are stuck staring at an error message, scratching their heads and trying to understand what a RenderFlex is.

https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-tutorial-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Like this,Instead of Expanded use flexible with container

[image: Row input with phone icon in the left]

```
Row(
  children:<Widget>[ 
    Icon(Icons.settings_cell),
    SizedBox(width: 10 ),
    Text("+60",),
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 14, 0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 1,
        height: 12,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffCCCCCC)),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: TextField(
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff666666),
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText:'phone number',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFCCCCCC),
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none
          ),
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
          ],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          cursorColor: Color(0xFF1FA2FF),        
        ) 
      )
    )
  ]
),
```

Comment: If constrain the height of a row, it looks like there's a problem

Comment: Are you want to increase the size of font, icon and text field or just height of row ?

Comment: I try to wrap row in the container and set the height. If I don't do this, row will be opened with a blank by flexible, which is also pretty, but I can't control the height of the blank

Comment: Try adding flex:2 in flexible and change the size of icon , text , text field as you want. It will increase height of rows. But I'm not sure this is what you were asking.